# Reading & Modifying line from File

Tags: python

I want the user to modify the line from file with some integers calculation included (calculation will obviously the program will do) however user provides the quantity.

my File contains:

```
You Have purchased 8 Bananas of 40$
You have purchased 2 Apples of 2$
```

now users select a line for eg line number 2 in this case. and then program asks for what you want to do edit or remove. If users select edit so it asks for quantity so if user input a quanity of 5 apples this time. I want the file to change that 2 to 5 and also calculate the total price by using a simple formula. meaning the original quanity divided by price so we will get the original price then it multiplies by the new quanity and save in that location of 2$. and after changing this line saves back to the file in its original location.

**What i have tried:**

```
line = f.readlines()
option = int(input('Select line number to edit or remove:'))
selectedline = line[option-1]
print(selectedline,'[Selected]')
action = int(input('''What you want to do
[1] Edit Quantity
[2] Remove
'''))
edit = selectedline.split()    

if action == 1:
    qty = int(input('Enter new quanity'))
    edit[-1] = edit[3]/edit[-1]
    edit[3] = qty
    edit[-1] = qty*edit[-1]
    print(edit)
```

but the problem is when i use split the data goes into the list in the form of strings and error cant multiply and divide on strings. also how can i resave this line back to its original position.

Comment: type cast the string values to float `float(edit[3])/float(edit[-1])`, and while writing use `' '.join(edit)`, it will create a string using spaces from edit list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code:-

```
line = f.readlines()
option = int(input('Select line number to edit or remove:'))
selectedline = line[option-1]
print(selectedline,'[Selected]')
action = int(input('''What you want to do
[1] Edit Quantity
[2] Remove
'''))
edit = selectedline.split()    

if action == 1:
    qty = int(input('Enter new quanity'))
    edit[-1] = str(float(edit[3])/float(edit[-1]))
    edit[3] = str(qty)
    edit[-1] = str(qty)
    print(edit)
    line = ' '.join(edit)
    # use line as per your needs
```

Comment: The line=' '.join(edit) is giving error **TypeError: sequence item 3: expected str instance, int found** . 
Can you explain this part little bit

Comment: it was due to the int type of item 3, now we have also type casted it back to string, try the updated code snippet, it will work. Use `float() str() int()` type cast function accordingly in your code.